Tidymodels workaround for kernlab "protection stack overflow" error
I am currently trying to make tidymodels work using kernlab in the backend. The problem I am facing is that I can't find a way around the "protect(): protection stack overflow" error.
I am aware that this problem is caused by too many variables and the "formula" expression. I know that in kernlab, this can be averted by using the x = and y = arguments and using a matrix instead of a data.frame.
My problem is that I cannot find a similar solution when using tidymodels. I suspect that the data is always transformed to a data.frame or data.table in the background. Has anyone already found a solution or workaround for this problem or am I missing something?
While it would technically be possible to do everything without tidymodels, I'd really like to use its streamlined preprocessing and especially tuning functionality.
I have already tried setting --max-ppsize to 500000
Here is a working example of the problem I am facing:
library(tidymodels)

x <- as.data.frame(matrix( rnorm(2000000), nrow = 100, ncol = 20000))
y <- data.frame("y" = rnorm(n = 100))

data <- cbind(y, x)

train.cv <- vfold_cv(data,5)
  
svm_model <- svm_rbf(
  cost = tune(),
  rbf_sigma = tune(),
  margin = tune(),
  engine = "kernlab",
  mode = "regression"
)

svm_recep <- recipe(x = as.matrix(data)) %>%
  update_role(everything(), new_role = "predictor") %>% 
  update_role(y, new_role = "outcome")

svm_wflow <- workflow(preprocessor = svm_recep, spec = svm_model)
  
svm_set <- extract_parameter_set_dials(svm_wflow)

hypercube <- grid_latin_hypercube(svm_set, size = 5)
  
svm_initial <-  svm_wflow %>%
  tune_grid(resamples = train.cv,
            grid = hypercube,
            metrics = metric_set(rmse))

Additionally, here an example of fixing the code in kernlab:
Same Error:
library(kernlab)

svm.train <- ksvm(y ~ ., type="eps-svr", data = data,
                  kernel ="rbfdot")

And fixing it:
library(kernlab)

svm.train <- ksvm(x = as.matrix(data[,-1]), y = as.matrix(data[,1]),type="eps-svr",
                  kernel ="rbfdot")

Because of this I suspect it's related to the data.frame format or the formula expression.
I'd appreciate any ideas or help regarding this!
Additional info:
> library(tidymodels)
── Attaching packages ───────────────────────────── tidymodels 1.2.0 ──
✔ broom        1.0.5      ✔ recipes      1.0.10
✔ dials        1.2.1      ✔ rsample      1.2.1 
✔ dplyr        1.1.4      ✔ tibble       3.2.1 
✔ ggplot2      3.5.0      ✔ tidyr        1.3.1 
✔ infer        1.0.7      ✔ tune         1.2.1 
✔ modeldata    1.3.0      ✔ workflows    1.1.4 
✔ parsnip      1.2.1      ✔ workflowsets 1.1.0 
✔ purrr        1.0.2      ✔ yardstick    1.3.1 

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Berlin
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] kernlab_0.9-32     yardstick_1.3.1    workflowsets_1.1.0
 [4] workflows_1.1.4    tune_1.2.1         tidyr_1.3.1       
 [7] tibble_3.2.1       rsample_1.2.1      recipes_1.0.10    
[10] purrr_1.0.2        parsnip_1.2.1      modeldata_1.3.0   
[13] infer_1.0.7        ggplot2_3.5.0      dplyr_1.1.4       
[16] dials_1.2.1        scales_1.3.0       broom_1.0.5       
[19] tidymodels_1.2.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.1    timeDate_4022.108   blob_1.2.3         
 [4] fastmap_1.1.0       digest_0.6.35       rpart_4.1.23       
 [7] timechange_0.3.0    lifecycle_1.0.3     ellipsis_0.3.2     
[10] survival_3.5-8      RSQLite_2.2.20      magrittr_2.0.3     
[13] compiler_4.3.3      rlang_1.1.3         tools_4.3.3        
[16] utf8_1.2.2          data.table_1.14.2   bit_4.0.4          
[19] DiceDesign_1.9      withr_2.5.0         nnet_7.3-19        
[22] grid_4.3.3          fansi_1.0.3         colorspace_2.0-3   
[25] future_1.33.2       globals_0.16.2      iterators_1.0.14   
[28] MASS_7.3-60.0.1     cli_3.6.2           generics_0.1.2     
[31] rstudioapi_0.16.0   future.apply_1.10.0 DBI_1.2.2          
[34] cachem_1.0.6        stringr_1.5.0       splines_4.3.3      
[37] parallel_4.3.3      vctrs_0.6.5         hardhat_1.3.1      
[40] Matrix_1.5-1        bit64_4.0.5         listenv_0.9.0      
[43] foreach_1.5.2       gower_1.0.1         glue_1.6.2         
[46] parallelly_1.34.0   codetools_0.2-19    lubridate_1.9.3    
[49] stringi_1.7.6       gtable_0.3.0        munsell_0.5.0      
[52] GPfit_1.0-8         pillar_1.9.0        furrr_0.3.1        
[55] ipred_0.9-14        lava_1.7.2.1        R6_2.5.1           
[58] lhs_1.1.6           lattice_0.22-5      backports_1.4.1    
[61] memoise_2.0.1       class_7.3-22        Rcpp_1.0.12        
[64] prodlim_2023.03.31  pkgconfig_2.0.3  


tidymodels does not use kernlab's formula method; try running translate() on svm_model to see what it invokes.

I suspect that the issue is driven by the tuning parameter grid that you are using. You might look at those values and see if altering them helps. Also, are you running this in parallel (and if so, how)?

When tidymodels calls kernlab to carry out the model fit, it always calls the formula interface of kernlab::ksvm(). We've opened an issue to consider changing which interface we use internally for kernlab. So while you can't trigger kernlab's matrix interface from tidymodels atm, something along the lines of

I have already tried setting --max-ppsize to 500000
might be a way in the meantime?


Yep. My comment above is wrong; I was deceived since ksvm uses the argument x as the formula (and not, you know, $X$)

Thank you very much for your comments, suggestions and opening an issue. I have (somewhat) solved the problem by setting the suggested --max-ppsize to 500000 (which is the maximum) and setting options("expressions"=5e5) (also maximum) in R. The downside is that parallelization using doParallel and makeCluster() does not work (again, results in protect() stack overflow errors).
In case other users have the same problem: I could not get this solution to work in RStudio, but it did work in RGui and Emacs. I don't know if this is just my lack of skills or a problem with RStudio.
